Does a Singleton allocates memory if they're not being called?
Does a Singleton allocates memory if they're not being called? For example:
public class CameraShake : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Make it singleton
    #region Singleton
    public static CameraShake instance { get; private set; };
    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
    }
    #endregion
 
    public void Function() {// Code here...}
 
}

Does it allocate the memory if we DIDN'T call it somewhere?

Why would a singleton be any different to any other class that you create instances of? Why should a singleton be any different to any other class that has static members?

Does it allocate the memory if we DIDN'T call it somewhere? .. call what exactly? The instance is static and either way will allocate an int reference pointer - regardless of whether it points to null or an existing instance, yes. Any instance fields are only allocated once you create an instance of this ... so the question is: Is there an instance in your scene somewhere or not?

Declaring the static property instance doesn't make it a singleton.

You are using a MonoBehaviour here, not a "real" singleton. A "real" singleton is created either at startup (or some initialization phase) or when needed using lazy initialization. A singleton is also not a static class. It is not created in the same way a static class is and therefore any rules regarding static classes do not apply here.
But since you are using a MonoBehaviour, you are using a managed object created by Unity and storing a reference to it as a static reference. For this singleton to exist and for instance to be ever valid, you have to add it to a GameObject in a way (either in the editor or by using AddComponent<T>() on a GameObject.
So for the singleton part of your object to exist, there needs to be an instance beforehand that then gets Awake() called by Unity. Therefore, your object will always allocate memory, regardless if you access it via the static member or not. It will not allocate memory if you don't create it at any point in the lifetime of your application, but that is not related to the singleton aspect at all, that's just you not spawning the object in the engine.

For it to behave like a true singleton, you could implement the property in a different way, doing something like this:
private static CameraShake instance;
public static CameraShake Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            var gameObject = new GameObject();
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            instance = gameObject.AddComponent<CameraShake>();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

This will create your instance and allocate its memory only when you access it via the property. What it doesn't do is prevent you from creating new instances that would have to be checked in Awake().

To make this more complete: Before new GameObject you could also add a check for if(instance == null) instance = FindAnyObjectByType<CameraShake>(); in order to cover for an eventually already existing instance in the scene but this property being accessed before CameraShake.Awake has been called (e.g. for instance within another class' Awake)

I have an aditional question. If I derive from MonoBehaviour, and implement Singleton (like the code I gave above), would it be allocating memory? In other words, it DOESN'T do "Lazy Initialization"

I answered this question in the third paragraph.

Long story short, every single piece of data in your program allocates memory. There is no matter is it a static class, static field, class, method, instances of classes and structs, singleton with static access to instance, singleton, lifecycle of which controlled by DI, or whatever else.
The difference is where the allocation happens. Static classes placed in special memory space, reserved for static data. Classes instances are placed in the heap or large objects heap. Structs instances are placed in the stack, and so on.

So, does doing Singleton would be a good idea for ALL of functions in my game? Would it be expensive on the memory side?

Should you use a Singleton as its representation with static access to the instance is, basically, an opinion based question. IMHO Singleton pattern could be useful for quick prototyping, but makes a lot of pain in big complicated projects. Therefore, in general usage, Singleton should not cause performance problems related to the memory.

According to Microsoft's documentation :

As is the case with all class types, the .NET runtime loads the type information for a static class when the program that references the class is loaded. The program can't specify exactly when the class is loaded. However, it's guaranteed to load and have its fields initialized and its static constructor called before the class is referenced for the first time in your program. A static constructor is only called one time, and a static class remains in memory for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program resides.

I'm not an expert regarding memory allocation but this seems quite clear to me.
Edit : even if in your example, CameraShake is not a static class, I will quote the documentation again.

Creating a static class is therefore basically the same as creating a class that contains only static members and a private constructor. A private constructor prevents the class from being instantiated. The advantage of using a static class is that the compiler can check to make sure that no instance members are accidentally added. The compiler guarantees that instances of this class can't be created.

